# Do Cascade and Epic work together?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Spells that have *Epic*, such as [Neverending Torment](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNeverending%20Torment%5d) prevent you from casting any more spells outside of the copy that you cast of it each turn. But, does playing a card count as casting a spell? I am specifically asking about cards that give *Cascade*, such as [Maelstrom Nexus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bMaelstrom%20Nexus%5d).

Would I get a *Cascade* trigger off of the *Epic* spell copy?

Comment: I've switched to use the spiffy `[mtg:Card Name]` template on this site, rather than embedding images of the cards. Among other things, this allows users with screen readers to be able to read a text version of the card on the page that comes up.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, Cascade and Epic don't work together.

Epic creates a copy of that spell on the stack, which then resolves.

Cascade responds to spell *casting.* Copying a spell is not casting it. You can frequently see that on the rulings on cards that copy spells, such as on [Insidious Will](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bInsidious%20Will%5d):

> The copy is created on the stack, so it’s not “cast.” Abilities that trigger when a player casts a spell won’t trigger.

The final nail in the coffin is that Epic says “you can't cast spells”. If somehow you *did* trigger Cascade, you would not be allowed to cast the spell you cascaded down to. Of course, you wouldn't be able to cast spells to trigger Cascade in the first place. (Thanks @Gendolkari.)

Only the original casting of the Epic spell will trigger Cascade. That will be the final Cascade you will see this game.